# auto_route ExtendedNavigator.builder() suddenly expects 'RouterBase' after migrating

Tags: flutter, dart, migration

after trying to upgrade to Flutter 2 the ExtendedNavigator.builder<***app_router.Router***> expects RouterBase class or subclass and I can't find a way around it.

```
import 'package:auto_route/auto_route.dart';
import 'package:routes/router.gr.dart' as app_router;

...

child: MaterialApp(
        builder: ExtendedNavigator.builder<app_router.Router>(
          router: app_router.Router(),
          navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
        ),
       ),
```

> 'Router' doesn't conform to the bound 'RouterBase' of the type parameter 'T'.
> Try using a type that is or is a subclass of 'RouterBase'.dart(type_argument_not_matching_bounds)

Comment: Any clues so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'auto_route/auto_route.dart';
import 'router.gr.dart' as app_router;

  return MaterialApp(
   builder: ExtendedNavigator.builder<app_router.Router>(router: app_router.Router()),
   ...
  );
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.